# Adding anchor tag for image in Cleditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, cleditor

I am using [Cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) for my project. I need to add hyperlink for my image. But if I select image the `add hyperlink` is not working. But if I select any text the add hyperlink is works well. Is there any way to `add hyperlink` for image?

**Update 2**

Here I have given the demo page of [Cleditor Demo](https://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/simpledemo). On this page please upload a image using `Insert image` link. And then select the image that you have uploaded and click `Insert Hyperlink` button. On that case I cannot able to add link for image.

Comment: have you tried CKeditor ?

Comment: Actually this project is almost done, so now cannot able to change :(

Comment: can you give me the steps to reproduce the problem you are facing as it's not very clear from your question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please see the update 2

Comment: on the above demo page everything is deactivated, When I click on insert image nothing happens.

Comment: You can find insert image button as 7th option from the last. And also if you click the button it will ask the http url of the image. just put any image link from live.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121826/discussion-between-praveen-srinivasan-and-raghvendra-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Please first select the image that you have inserted as you would select any text before turning it into a hyperlink.

I have tried and it works. After you insert the image just select it like a regular block of text and click on insert hyperlink.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried, it asks a selection is need to insert link. I have selected the image.